# Firefox and Chrome give different values for offsetTop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position an span element (let us call it "the tooltip span") relative to a input field. To do this, I am wrapping the tooltip span and the input field in another span element (let's call it "the wrapper span") that has `position: relative`. Then I set `position: absolute` on tooltip span. This makes the tooltip span position itself relative to the wrapper span but not being part of the page flow - not taking up any space. This is exactly what I want.

Then, using javascript, I set the position of the tooltip relative to the position of the input element. Since the input element can be shaped differently on different pages (script should be globablly applicable), I am using its `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` properties to calculate its position relative to the wrapper span.

However, I am noticing inconsistencies between browsers here. In Firefox, IE6, 7, 8, it works as expected. But in Chrome and Safari the reported `offsetTop` seems, well, incorrect.

To prove this, I created the test page below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
span { font-size: 8px; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; border: 1px solid red } 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<span id="wrapper">
<input id="foo" name="foo" type="text">
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<br>Offset parent: " + document.getElementById("foo").offsetParent.id);
document.write("<br>Offset top: " + document.getElementById("foo").offsetTop);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and loaded it in Firefox and Chrome. Both browser report the wrapper span as its `offsetParent`, but for Firefox the `offsetTop` is -8 and for Chrome it is 2. Visually the page renders the same in both browsers.

This gives me a headache, because I cannot just hack in a different offset that I always apply when someone is using Chrome, because if I change the font size, the `offsetTop` will not change, and my script will break.

Is this a bug? Can I solve this differently?

Comment: Try waiting until the document is ready

Comment: I did this in the "real" code: doesn't seem to matter. I've inspected the offsetTop in Firebug and in the Chrome developer window and the values are the same.

Comment: I've moved label tags like this (validation error message: http://d.pr/i/yvGS) by making them inline-block (along with postion:absolute;) then using margin to position them relative to it's placement in the HTML, instead of top/right/bottom/left properties. Might workout, if it does you could avoid extra javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery. DOM differences between browsers is one of the things it excels at.

Comment: Holy rusted metal! I was going to say that this is not one of those problems where JQuery is the answer. But it turns out that there is a position() function I was not aware of, that really does the trick. The question still remains why Chrome/Safari reports the offset differently. But you get the check.

Answer (score 17):

You Can try using

```
$(window).load
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready
```

because Explorer and Chrome sets proper offsets only after images have been fully loaded.

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the same problem as you and I realized that (in my case) the thing that was messing up the offset().top value in chrome, was having one or more images without the "height" attribute above the element.

**Before**

```
<img src="/images/foo.jpg" />
```

offset.top() was 100 in Chrome

offset.top() was 150 in Firefox and IE7 (beleive or not, it worked just fine in IE!)

**After**

```
<img src="/images/foo.jpg" height="50" width="50" />
```

offset.top() is 150 in both Firefox, IE7, **AND CHROME.**

*Notice the the difference was 50px, which is actually the same as the image height.*

Since I was developing a JQuery plugin, i tryed to collect all the images that had their width and height attributes undefined, and manually setting their size with .width() and .height(), but it didn't work, because Chrome returned 0 for both functions. So, i guess the problem with offset.top() actually relies on that. If JQuery is triying to get te offset.top() value by accumulating the "above" element's height, and one of those elements it's an image with no specified height, "0" will be added to that sum, and therefore the top value will be missing those "ignored" heights.

PS: Sorry for my english, it's been a long time since i wrote such a *long* text in this language!

Answer (score 2):

Put you code into a `window.onload` function.  I recall having issues when attempting to work with the dom directly from a `<script>` during page load in firefox, and webkit tends to be slightly more willing to give a sane DOM at such points.

This is just based on prior issues i've encountered, i'm not sure if it's applicable to your case.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, and jQuery's position() function was reporting the same as the offset() function. Ultimately it turns out that even waiting for the document to be ready didn't work for me. I had to check offset() later in the flow (in my case, in my handler that is fired on a window.scroll event).

When I try this test code below, on page load, I get different figures for Firefox + Chrome. Once it loads, however, I can press 'd' and I get the same figure for both browsers.

```
// this produced different results on Chrome + Firefox (Chrome was wrong!)
$(document).ready(function () {
   var x =  $('#some-div-on-your-page').position().top;
   alert("On load, offset is "+x);   // Chrome + Firefox report diff figures

  $(window).keydown(function(e, r) {
     k = e ? e.keyCode : event.keyCode;
     if(k == 68) {      // press 'd'
        var x =  $('#some-div-on-your-page').position().top;
        alert("Now the offset is "+x); // ...but this is consistent
     }
   });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem, and tried adding to my function

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

and it worked in both Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

If you get "0" in chrome, see if you are targeting an empty element like "a". It needs to wrap something in order to return the correct offset.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the different border/margin values for the HTML and body elements that browsers set by default.