# Why offsetTop returns different value in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, css, angular, cross-browser

We are working on angular application in which we need to show one element on top of the page after browser's scroll reach to that element.

Is there any CSS issue which is impacted.

Below is the code.

```
elementRef.nativeElement.offsetParent.offsetTop;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472842/firefox-and-chrome-give-different-values-for-offsettop

Comment: @DhananjaiPai Solution provided in jQuery which is not works for angular.

Comment: @SantoshShelke what exactly is not working?

Comment: @AmirArbabian not getting correct value in Chrome. In IE it's working fine. This is cross browser issue.

Comment: Most people write CSS rules to reset to a default set of settings. http://cssdesignpatterns.com/ This resource helped me when I started out for that kind of stuff.

Comment: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ This is used by Bootstrap for example

Comment: https://caniuse.com/