# CSS not working in Firefox and Safari, but works perfectly in Chrome

Tags: css, html

My CSS is not working properly in firefox and safari
Here is my website link and use Audrey password for access
https://audrey-landon.myshopify.com/products/collection-item-3#
Please see a select size option

```
select `#productSelect option.not_avalble:before` {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-color: #222323;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Having an issue on CSS code

Comment: Please add codes for browser, by detecting browser

Comment: Hello Xavier
Am just creating a dropdown option as inline-block 
Please visit to my mentioned link 
And see my code in inspect element

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to inspect your codes, please try with the browser specific codes it will works  :)

Comment: Have a look at my comments on this similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604098/why-offsettop-returns-different-value-in-chrome-and-ie#comment96006454_54604098